# Replace substrings with elements of a list of tuples

Tags: python, replace, tuples

I have a string as such:

```
string = """
 foobar_tent\n
 missyamica_ole
 """
```

this is a list of tuples I have:

```
 t = [("foo","virtue"), ("ole, "allo")]
```

I'm trying to replace every instance of the first element of each tuple with the second element of each tuple. So the result would be this:

```
newstring = """
 virtuebar_tent
 missyamica_allo
 """"
```

I tried doing it as such, but it doesn't alter anything.

```
newstring = ""
for a,b in t:
     newstring = string.replace(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were basically right. Main issue is that you were doing string.replace each time so only the last of your replacements in the list would have worked.

```
newstring = string
for a,b in t:
    newstring = newstring.replace(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`newstring` is overwritten in the loop by replaced original string.

Use `newstring.replace` instead of `string.replace`, so that the replaced string is not to be overwritten.

```
>>> string = """
... foobar_tent
... missyamica_ole
... """
>>> t = [("foo", "virtue"), ("ole", "allo")]
>>>
>>> newstring = string  # <-----
>>> for a,b in t:
...     newstring = newstring.replace(a,b) # <----
...
>>> newstring
'\nvirtuebar_tent\nmissyamica_allo\n'
>>> print(newstring)

virtuebar_tent
missyamica_allo
```